# Flask run shows invalid syntax **response

Tags: python, flask

While doing flask run it shows error.

```
File "/home/rexweb/Desktop/SSP/Projects/Wundershots/uw-api/api/modules/utilities.py", line 336
    response = {**response, **self.additional_params}
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please let me know if anyone has any idea about the same?

Comment: You can't have two `**kwargs` arguments to a function like that. Please show us your code, and hopefully we can say what you should be doing instead, but we tan't tell that from the error message alone.

Comment: @brunns, that is not a function call, it is a dictionary assignment where two other dictionaries are unpacked into it.

Comment: Ah, right. Still - let's see the code so we can help.

Comment: What version of Python are you running? Unpacking in a "dictionary display", such as your example, is only supported in Python 3.5 and up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am using another command:

`sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flask`

it works for me.....

Comment: you shouldn't be running docker as `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using dictionary unpacking in a 'dictionary display', this is [only supported from Python 3.5 and on](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).